# Django & GDAL - Could not find the GDAL library

Tags: django, homebrew, geospatial, gdal, apple-m1

I have a macbook with the M1 Chip and I'm trying to set up a django project. The project works with Geospatial libraries gdal.
I installed gdal with homebrew on version 3.3.1_3 and inside my virtual env version 3.3.1

If I type `python manage.py migrate` I get an error:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cloud not find the GDAL
> library (tried "gdal", "GDAL", "gdal3.1.0", "gdal3.0.0", "gdal2.4.0",
> "gdal2.3.0", "gdal2.2.0", "gdal2.1.0"). Is GDAL installed? If it is,
> try settings GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings.

By pip list shows me GDAL at version 3.1.0. The **Django Docs** say version 3.3.x is not supported but I cant install a specific gdal version with homebrew.

Is there a different solution to get the django project up and running?

Comment: Suggest setting up your virtual env using [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html).  You will have more control over the versions, and the gdal binaries will get installed in there.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately the suggestions by @Ameya didn't work for me, but they did send me down the right path in my investigation. The root cause of my issue was related to python ctypes, from the **pyenv** distro that I use, not being able to find the GDAL shared library installed from **homebrew**. Below are some other explanations that I found during my investigation.

The following thread on python bugs gives some good background and detail into Apple's semi-recent(?) increased security constraints that were causing the underlying issue:

https://bugs.python.org/issue43964

This post on pyenv's github gives excellent detail on the issue and why pyenv does not have a general purpose solution:

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/2339

Here is one way to test if you are having the same underlying issue that I did. Start a python shell and try to manually load the library with ctypes:

> ╰─➤ python3
> Python 3.10.8 (main, Dec  5 2022, 14:59:49) [Clang 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)] on darwin
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> --> from ctypes.util import find_library
> --> find_library('libgdal.dylib')

If ctypes finds the library, a path is shown. If no lib is found, no response is given.

It appears that the ctypes loader now(?) only has a fixed set of paths on macos. The work-around that I used is to simply find one of the existing paths that was not used. I then created a symbolic link there, pointing to the homebrew libs location. For example ctypes appears to search $HOME/lib and /usr/local/lib, both of which were empty (or non-existent) on my machine. So I created a symbolic link as follows:

> ╰─➤ sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/lib /usr/local/lib

or

> ╰─➤ ln -s /opt/homebrew/lib ~/lib

Now ctypes finds the library and as a result, django starts properly:

> ╰─➤  python3
> Python 3.10.8 (main, Dec  5 2022, 14:59:49) [Clang 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)] on darwin
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> --> from ctypes.util import find_library
> --> find_library('libgdal.dylib')
> '/usr/local/lib/libgdal.dylib'
> -->

Comment: Dude, you are my hero! This works. Thank you so much.

Comment: respect++, mad mad respect

Answer (score 5):

I happen to own new MacBook M1 Pro and facing some issue. Here are the steps I did that helped me resolved this issue.

**Step 1:** First check whether you have installed gdal and geos.

```
gdal-config --version
```

If no version shows up, then run `brew install gdal` in your terminal.

**Step 2:** Find out path of your gdal installation.

```
which gdal-config
```

This should return in case of M1 Mac OS -

```
/opt/homebrew/opt/gdal/bin
```

**Step 3:** Check if gdal lib file is present in below location.

```
/opt/homebrew/opt/gdal/lib/libgdal.dylib
```

If it does, then great! Do the same setps for geos if you require that as well.

Once all done, in your Django Project in Settings.py,
Add below lines.

```
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = '/opt/homebrew/opt/gdal/lib/libgdal.dylib'

GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = '/opt/homebrew/opt/geos/lib/libgeos_c.dylib'
```

It should work now. Also if you have installed and using PostgreSQL it does come with GDAL and GEOS libs, you can also give those paths as well if needed.